# Java error @d622e5

Tags: java, object

```
class Tank{
    int level;
}
class aliasing{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Tank t1 = new Tank();
        Tank t2 = new Tank();

        t1.level=21;
        t2.level=32;
        System.out.println("t1: " + t1 + " t2: " + t2);
    }
}
```

This block of code produces the output: t1: Tank@1b4b24d t2: Tank@260829. Obviously this is wrong, but i don't know why all of a sudden all my code is producing nosense. Also, if i just intiliaze a primitive value i can print that out no problem with the correct value, so i don't know why only objects are messing up.

Comment: What output do you expect and why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the toString() method in Tank class to produce meaningful representation of your object.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing the correct output. As can be seen in [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) documentation, the default is to print the name of the class, an `@` character and the hash of the specific object.

The hashes both differ as they are two different objects. If you were to set `t1 = t2 = new Tank();` then you would see the hashes match up as well.